# Fabricjs line coordinates after (moved, scaled, rotated) - canvas.on('object:modified'…

Tags: line, coordinates, fabricjs

I need to find the **Line coordinates(x1,y1,x2,y2)** after the object has been modified. (moved, scaled, rotated)

I thought to use the **oCoords** information and based on angle and flip information to decide which corners are the line ends, but it seems that it will not be too accurate…

Any help?

**Example:**

x1: **164**,

y1: 295.78334045410156,

x2: **451**,

y2: 162.78334045410156

x: **163**, y: 161.78334045410156 - top left corner

x: **452**, y: 161.78334045410156 - top right corner

x: 163, y: 296.78334045410156 - bottom left corner

x: 452, y: 296.78334045410156 - bottom right corner

Comment: Are you calling setCoords() method on your line object before retrieving oCoords values ?

Comment: I have not used it, but even with it remains the difference of 1 pixel. I have all objects with origin - "center". Do you know if the corners have this property, and that to be the reason(if it is not set), or maybe they  are moved slightly out of the real ends by default?

Comment: The fabric Line Object has the proprties: x1,y1,x2,y2. After performing that transform aren't the values updated to the real ones ?

Comment: No they remain the same as **originalState**

Comment: Anyway thanks for the help I decided to ignore the discripancy and to use them.

Answer (score 0):

When Fabric.js calculates `oCoords` - i.e. object's corners' coordinates - it takes into account the object's `strokeWidth`:

```
// fabric.Object.prototype
_getNonTransformedDimensions: function() {
  var strokeWidth = this.strokeWidth,
      w = this.width + strokeWidth,
      h = this.height + strokeWidth;
  return { x: w, y: h };
},
```

For most objects, `stroke` is kind of a border that outlines the outer edges, so it makes perfect sense to account for `strokeWidth` it when calculating corner coordinates.

In `fabric.Line`, though, `stroke` is used to draw the body of the line. There is no example in the question but I assume this is the reason behind discrepancies between the real end-point coordinates and those in `oCoords`.

So, if you *really* want to use `oCoords` to detect the coordinates of the end points, you'll have to adjust for `strokeWidth / 2`, e.g.

```
const realx1 = line.oCoords.tl.x + line.strokeWidth / 2
const realy1 = line.oCoords.tl.y + line.strokeWidth / 2
```

Keep in mind that `fabric.Line`'s own `_getNonTransformedDimensions()` *does* adjust for `strokeWidth`, but only when the line's `width` or `height` equal 0:

```
// fabric.Line.prototype
_getNonTransformedDimensions: function() {
  var dim = this.callSuper('_getNonTransformedDimensions');
  if (this.strokeLineCap === 'butt') {
    if (this.width === 0) {
      dim.y -= this.strokeWidth;
    }
    if (this.height === 0) {
      dim.x -= this.strokeWidth;
    }
  }
  return dim;
},
```